# Why can't I join or complete jobs?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I have huge troubles getting to play any jobs in GTA Online. I open my cell phone and accept a job, the job is either canceled straight away, I get some message that I was unable to connect, the leader leaves, no one else joins or I am kicked.

Also, the loading in between can take minutes. If a job gets started after hours of trying someone leaves in the middle and its canceled. Is this how it is for everyone? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: www.speedtest.net . It would help to know how fast your internet is, thank you! :)

Comment: I play on Xbox One and haven't seen this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to the NAT type of my xbox was set to strict. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ebAvO3ZvHQE) guide fixed it.

Comment: You should summarize what the guide says in your answer. Just in case the site you linked ever goes down. Otherwise your answer would become useless if this would ever happen.